# Python 2.7 + flask wrong storing to DB

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, psql

I'm trying to have web form for inserting latitude, longitude, message and date/time to DB using Python 2.7 and flask framework. Unfortunately it is not properly stored in the DB and I'm getting crazy as I cannot find bug in my code.

having this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_pyfile('conf.cfg')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# create DB structure 
class Sprava(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'spravy'
    id = db.Column('spravy_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    lat = db.Column(db.Float)
    lon = db.Column(db.Float)
    text = db.Column(db.String)
    pub_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def __init__(self, lat, lon, text):
        self.lat = lat
        self.lat = lon
        self.text = text
        self.pub_date = datetime.utcnow()

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/hello')

# index page
def index():
    return 'Hello sledovanie'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()


# web form
from flask import Flask, request, flash, url_for, redirect, render_template, abort 

@app.route('/sledovanie', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new():
    if request.method == 'POST':
            sprava = Sprava(request.form['lat'], request.form['lon'], request.form['text'])
            db.session.add(sprava)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('sledovanie.html')
```

When I fill in the web form or during debugging using this simple piece of code:

```
z = Sprava('1', '2', 'text_i')
db.session.add(z)
db.session.commit()
```

It will not get it to the DB (psql_9.2) correctly. This what is stored into database:

```
 spravy_id | lat | lon |  text  |          pub_date          
-----------+-----+-----+--------+----------------------------
         1 |   2 |     | text_i | 2014-08-03 17:02:43.829942
```

Id is OK
lat is lon
lon is missing
text OK
date OK

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `self.lat = lon` => please close as typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `__init__` has a typo.

```
self.lat = lat
self.lat = lon
```

You see the problem above ? Also, due to this typo, you are not setting `self.lan` at all.

Obviously, this is probably a typo you have and you know the fix. But just in case, you need to do

```
def __init__(self, lat, lon, text):
    self.lat = lat
    self.lon = lon
    self.text = text
    self.pub_date = datetime.utcnow()
```